# how to change a value from text input into dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller like this: `unitselector.php`

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Unitselector extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //$this->load->model(array('Transaksi_model', 'Pelanggan_model'));
    //chek_session();
}

function index() {
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        // redirect them to the login page
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    } else{
        $this->db->order_by("unit_order");
        $data['record']=  $this->db->get('tb_unit_list')->result();
        $unitid = $this->input->get('hiddenInput');
        $data['record1']=  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_unit_location where id_unit='$unitid' ")->result();
        $data['record2']=  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_period WHERE Status = 0")->result();
        $this->load->view('unitselector/unitselector',$data);
    }
}

}
```

THE VIEW: unitselector

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Unit Name</label>
                        <select id='dropdown1' name='dropdown1' class="form-control" onclick="changeHiddenInput(this)">
                            <option value="">Pilih...</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($record)) {
                                foreach ($record as $r) {
                                    echo "<option value=".$r->id_unit.">".$r->unit_name."</option>";                                        
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <input  name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" value="" />     
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Lokasi/Cabang</label>
                        <select id='dropdown2' name='dropdown2' class="form-control" onclick="changeHiddenInput1(this)">
                            <option value="">Pilih...</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($record1)) {
                                foreach ($record1 as $r1) {
                                    echo "<option value=".$r1->id_unit_loc.">".$r1->unit_loc_name."</option>";                                        
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <input  name="hiddenInput1" id="hiddenInput1" value="" />       
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Periode</label>
                        <select id='dropdown3' name='dropdown3' class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Pilih...</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($record2)) {
                                foreach ($record2 as $r2) {
                                    echo "<option value=".$r2->id_period.">".$r2->id_period."</option>";                                        
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4" style="float: right;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"><?php echo lang('login_proceed');?></button>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close();?>              <!--Excutor when button submit goes to controller Dashboard.php -->
```

question is:

when the user select dropdown1 it return value to `hiddeninput`. i need `hiddeninput1` to become as search criteria on

```
$data['record1']=  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_unit_location where id_unit='$unitid' ")->result();
```

i already define `%unitid` as the value. but it does not effect. please help.

Comment: What are your javascript functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('#dropdown1').change(function(){
    window.location.href = 'unitselector/index?hiddenInput1=' + $(this).val();
});
```

Or use ajax loading.

Comment: Hi Maxim, thank you for your kindly solution. How do i apply in my code? in the controller or in the view?

Comment: $('#dropdown1').change(function(){
    window.location.href = 'unitselector/index?hiddenInput1=' + $(this).val();
}); // in view

Comment: Hi Maxim, thank you very much it's working :) , buat the text from dropdown1 disappearing when clicked.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dropdown1').change( function() {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>unitselector/index?hiddenInput=" + $(this).val();
    //history.pushState(null, 'Unit Selector', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>unitselector/index?hiddenInput=' + $(this).val());
    //$('#dropdown2').val('');
    //window.history.back();
    //window.history.forward();
    //window.history.go(2);
   });
  }); I tried to put this command but after that the value doesn;t change